# How to hyperlink to newly created sheet, in the same worksheet iv VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I've never been good in VBA but after long time of no use I am out of ideas even more.
I've written a macro which (among other things):

1. On button creates a new line with given properties.
2. User of excel can manually input the number of the record in column A.
3. With active cell of that number, on click of button it creates new sheet using template and names it as the number from the active cell.

In the next step I want to create a hyperlink on the number of the record refering to that newly created sheet, and preferably move to the new sheet.

What I have creates the hyperlink but in the new sheet:

```
Sub HistoriaDostaw()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim activeWB As Workbook
Dim FilePath As String
Dim ShtName As String
Dim CopyInfo As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False


Set activeWB = Application.ActiveWorkbook
FilePath = activeWB.Path & "\HistoriaDostawca.xltm"

On Error Resume Next


If ActiveCell.Column <> 1 Or ActiveCell.Value2 = "" Then

    MsgBox "Zaznacz liczbe porzadkowa w kolumnie A!", vbCritical, "Blad"
    Exit Sub

Else: ShtName = ActiveCell.Value2
End If

If Not WorkSheetExists(ShtName) Then

Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
wb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count)


ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="ShtName!A1"


activeWB.Activate

activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count).Name = ShtName

wb.Close False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Your question is not really clear. At least for me... So, do you want creating a Hyperlink **in the same sheet**, as it is stated in the question title? Or, you need to create the Hyperlink **in the initially active sheet**, but targeting the newly created one?

Comment: Perhaps my question was not clear. I have a main sheet containing list of subcontractors, each with individual number. The details of that subcontractor are contained in the separate sheet, named after that individual number. I want to create the hyperling on that number targeting the sheet with the details.

Comment: I am afraid that you did not clarify too much. Firstly, `On Error Resume Next` does not help at all in this context. It only do not let you to see what problem your code has. Then, the active sheet of your code will be the newly added sheet. Is this what you want? If yes,  I have some doubts that you really want a Hyperlink for the sheet itself. Am I wrong? You probably need a Hyperlink to target that `ShtName` defined before. Is this assumption correct? But if you will answer after other 4-5 hours, I am afraid that my enthusiasm in helping you will be tremendously diminished...

Comment: If that is the case, please do not bother with my question, sorry to waste your time. It is a side project I am working on in a free time. To answer your question, I need to create the Hyperlink in the initially active sheet, but targeting the newly created one. So, on click of button, it creates hyperlink on the number of subcontractor, e.g. "Subcontractor1", targeting newly created sheet named "Subcontractor1".

Comment: I is a little ridiculous to be **me** more interested in solving of your problem... I answered our comment at my answer code, asking for some clarifications. Since, it looks that your availability here is strangely low, I adapted my answer code according to the new supposition...

Answer (score 0):

Please, try replacing of:

```
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
wb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count)

ActiveCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="ShtName!A1"
```

with

```
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(FilePath)
Dim ShAct as worksheet, actCell as Range
Set ShAct = ActiveSheet: Set actCell = ActiveCell

wb.Worksheets(1).Copy After:=activeWB.Sheets(activeWB.Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = ShtName

ShAct.Hyperlinks.Add actCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & ShtName & "'!A1", TextToDisplay:="Go to" & ShtName
```

Comment: Thank you, but the effect is that it creates a hyberlinked text "Go to ShtName" in the newly created sheet. My point is to create hyperlink on number of subcontractor (located in the main active sheet), targeting the newly created sheet.

Comment: @Thomas: Where from the "number of subcontractor" to be taken? Shouldn't it be the name to be allocated to the newly creates sheet? I suppose you understand that the ActiveSheet, after opening the workbook, should be the active sheet when this workbook is open and its active cell should be previously memorized, in order to be used. Then, after copying the sheet, the active one is this newly created sheet. Not so easy to understand what you need, unfortunately. Anyhow, I will adapt the code to reflect the above descripted scenario. I only suppose that this is what you want...

Comment: @Thomas: Still alive? Do you really need our help?